# Twisted chainDeferred not working as expected

Tags: python, exception, twisted, deferred

I have a problem figuring out a somewhat simple twisted python code.
From what I have red in the docs, the code [here](http://pastebin.com/iuxVKamg) should work without Unhandled Error.

I get this:

```
HELLO!
HANDLED!
HANDLED 2!
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package_tester.py", line 31, in <module>
    a().callback(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "package_tester.py", line 5, in c
    raise Exception()
exceptions.Exception:
```

Isn't the failure from the chained deferred passed to end() errback ?

*For some reason I can't comment below Bula's post*
I managed to bypass the behaviour of 'unexpected1.py' by  simply adding

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def sync_deferred(self, result, deferred):
        """
        Wait for a deferred to end before continuing.
        @param deferred: deferred which will be waited to finish so the chain
        can continue.
        @return: result from the deferred.
        """
        r = yield deferred
        defer.returnValue(r)
```

sync_deferred after every chainDeferred, in which the result from a child deferred needs to be "waited" so the parent can continue with this result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post relevant code and error messages whenever possible. It's good form to reduce the amount of effort potential answerers would have to put in in order to figure out what your question means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of `Deferred.chainDeferred`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#chainDeferred):

```
When you chain a deferred d2 to another deferred d1 with d1.chainDeferred(d2),
you are making d2 participate in the callback chain of d1. Thus any event that
fires d1 will also fire d2.
```

The error you supply to `d1` (`d` in your example code) is passed on to `d2` (`l` in your example code).  This means that `d2`/`l` ends up with an error, which is passed to its first and only errback, `new_f`.  `new_f` returns its argument, leaving `d2`/`l` with an error result, which is not handled.

If you meant `new_f` to handle the failure, then you should make it ''not'' return a failure.  From [the `Deferred` howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto4):

```
If the errback does returns a Failure or raise an exception, then that is passed
to the next errback, and so on.
```

Comment: I think OP is surprised that after calling `d.addErrback(end)` `end` is not handling returnd failure from `new_f`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and full answer :) However, if I understood correctly, the deferreds are not only "chained", but Failure(if fired in the first deferred) has to be handled separately in every deferred down the chain.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://blogs.fluidinfo.com/terry/2010/08/14/twisteds-deferred-class-chaindeferred-method-is-too-simplistic/) excellent post there are few examples of potential problems that can arise when using `chainDeferred`. So when using this method one should be careful.